# Include user defined function in excel

Tags: excel

Is there a way to automatically include an add in/User defined function in excel?

Right now I have to manually open the add in file (.xla) Or enable it under 'Developer->Add-Ins->and then choose the .xla file.

I would like to be able to send the excel file to colleagues once it's done, and when they open the excel file, the user defined function will already be active.

Comment: You can embed the functions directly into a particular workbook. But that can cause a lot of code duplication.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for! :) Can you show me how to do it or give a link?

Comment: If you choose "Visual Basic Editor" (Alt + F11) from a spreadsheet, you're in the VBA environment.

Comment: Sorry I have never tried visual basic before, and I'm a novice at computers. Do I just embed it like this? It still doesn't work: http://imgur.com/JM0g2ez

Comment: Well, if you're in England, the weather's terrible. What better way is there to spend the rest of the day learning VBA?

Comment: Haha sorry, I accidently hit enter before finishing my message :P My bad

Comment: Wait wait, it's working now, doing as shown in the picture. The command just didn't work because the actual path for the add in was included. The commands work now :) Now I don't have to spend all day learning VBA. Thanks for the help :D